# Process two related list without (unnecessary) nested cycles

Tags: java, java-stream

I have list of Books and list of Authors. Books has only `authorId` (not whole object). And I need to process list of books several times (several different requirements). And some requirements needs data from Author as well.

So, clearly, there has to be a search for `Author` by it's `authorId`, for each book. But how to do that in optimal way (only once)?

```
Book book = ... 
Optional<Author> authorO = authors.stream
                               .filter(author -> author.getId().equals(book.getAuthorId()))
                               .findFirst();
```

I somehow guess that there should be a syntax in collection stream to "merge" two list together, and then (collect?) process the result several times.

So I would like something like this. Could you point me how to do that? Thank you.

```
List<Book> books = ...
List<Author> authors = ...

books.stream()
     .??? // stream of pairs? 
     .forEach((book, author) -> {
         processingOne(book, author);

         if (featureFlag2) {
             processingTwo(book, author);
         }

         // ...
    });
```

Comment: Not all processing of collections has to be done via the stream API. Are you insistent on using the stream API to perform your required processing?

Comment: agree, I just don't see a elegant solution so I asking. If you have a nice/elegant solution of any type/way just post it as a answer. Let say it could be reactive, using Flux processing... But the main question is to minimaze computational dificulty from m*n ... with as much as readability as possible.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you to create a map with `authorId` as the key and `Author` as the value, before starting to process the list of books:

```java
Map<Integer, Author> authorMap = authors.stream()
                                        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Author::getAuthorId,
                                                                  Function.identity()));
```

Then stream the books list and process it as:

```java
books.stream()   
     .forEach(book -> {
         Author author = authorMap.get(book.getAuthorId());
         processingOne(book, author);

         if (featureFlag2) {
             processingTwo(book, author);
         }

         //...
     });
```

**EDIT:** A different way to do the same thing. This approach makes use of **stateful** lambda.

```java
public Consumer<Book> processor(List<Author> authors, boolean featureFlag2) {
    // use concurrent map if you use parallelStream
    // authorMap is the state. It is created only once for the stream.
    Map<Integer, Author> authorMap 
        = authors.stream()
                 .collect(Collectors.toMap(Author::getAuthorId,
                                           Function.identity()));
    return book -> {
        Author author = authorMap.get(book.getAuthorId());
        processingOne(book, author);
        if (featureFlag2) {
            processingTwo(book, author);
        }
    };
}
```

Now use this `Consumer` in your stream.

```java
books.forEach(processor(authors, featureFlag2));
```

Comment: These approaches are identical. In the second, you just encapsulated a part of the first’s code into a method. By the way, instead of `books.stream() .forEach(…)` you can also write `books.forEach(…)`.

Comment: @Holger that's why i mentioned "a different way to do the same thing" :-) :-)

Comment: it looks like when a several processing is needed it will traverse the list several times...

Comment: @Wooff no both the lists would be traversed only once. authors list is traversed once to create the map and books list is traversed once to do the processing